Have any of the rules in the Ministry of Magic changed since Hermione became Minister of Magic?
The Ministry struggles with wizard trials and the rules are haphazard but sometimes understandable. Since Hermione is very sensible and dedicated to assisting other intelligent non-human species, rules might have changed.
Is there any evidence that any of the rules of the Ministry have changed in Harry Potter and the Cursed Child?
